# try-catch won't trigger when file already exists

Tags: powershell, zip, try-catch

I have a script that zips files from source for each year into year.zip format. It works fine, but in case if the zip already exists in the destination (same as source) I want to catch this exception and print it to the logs. Below is the code that I have to check if the file exists and then print it to the log. However, it is not doing just that. Can someone point out how to fix this?

Additionally, if zips do exist I want to undo transaction for that particular year (basically undo transaction of `[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $destination))`. I will appreciate if I can get pointers on this as well.

```
ForEach ($group in $groups){
# delete temp directorty to save space on C:\
if (test-path -path $GroupDirectory){
del $GroupDirectory -recurse -force
}

# Create a new directory for the group
$GroupDirectory = New-Item -Path (Join-Path $TmpDirectory.FullName -ChildPath $group.Name) -ItemType Directory
if (test-path -path $destination$GroupDirectory.zip){
    write-output $GroupDirectory.zip" already exists!"
}

# Move files into the new directory
$ZipNames = $group.Group | Move-Item -Destination $GroupDirectory.FullName

# Create the year-specific zip file
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($GroupDirectory.FullName, ($destination -f $group.Name))
```

}

Above code creates a folder named "2012" at temp location,...after that what I need is to check if there's file called "2012.zip" in the destination folder. Is test-path smart enough to know the difference?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the try block that would error or error with a `System.IO.IOException` exception.

Comment: the `Test-Path` cmdlet returns a `[bool]`. it doesn't actually _create an error_ when the item is not there - it just returns a `false`. so you can just use `if (Test-Path <path>) {do the found thing} else {do the not found thing}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Test-Path` won't return an exception; it will return `$true` or `$false`, i.e., a bool. You don't need to use try/catch for this. Just use if/else.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the code above but it's still not writing the file exists message to logs. Hmmm...I have a feeling it's because I am comparing a folder to a zip file for match? How do I achieve this?